# How to turn off old Mears M7-D thermostat controlling electric baseboard heating

Tags: electrical, heating, baseboard

I cannot figure out how to turn off the electric heating on this old unit that was installed probably around 50 years ago. Counterclockwise or clockwise, the electric heating element in the baseboard remains hot.

After removing the cover from the baseboard, I can even see a small red-hot bit glowing. Is it possible that "off" position lies in between?

The power is controlled by a tandem-20/20 breaker which I've flipped off for the time being.  That's the only way I've been able to cut the juice to the baseboard so that glow stops and the baseboard gets cool.

Mears M7-D
[image]

glowing heating element
[image]

[image: 20-amp twin breaker]

Comment: What is it that you're attempting to turn on that 1st pic? Also, I note that the labeling on the M7-D says "_22A_ 125, 250, or 277 VAC" - that means that your 20a breaker is probably a bit small and may end up tripping if the heater ever tries to draw full power.

Comment: The amperage capability of the thermostat does not imply anything about the amperage draw of the heater attached to it, and is fine so long as it's equal to or greater than it. But quite possibly the thermostat has failed.

Comment: @FreeMan: the vertical rod, if it is pinched between thumb and fingertip down at the bottom (where a round plastic piece fits onto it) can be rotated axially left (CCW) and right (CW).

Comment: Do you really mean a "double pole" breaker when you say "tandem"? Perhaps a photo of the breaker you had to flip could answer that even? Also, is there a nameplate *anywhere* on the heater?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: I don't see a name anywhere on the electric baseboard fixture. I'm adding a pic of the breaker.

Comment: @mrblint -- yeah, that breaker's double pole, *not* tandem/double-stuff (a tandem breaker has the two skinny handles in the same pole space, as you can see on the center right side of your photo of the breaker panel)

Comment: Many Line Voltage Thermostats do not have an off/on option, especially older ones. Mine does not. You can turn it to the lowest setting but there is no switch built into it for ON and OFF. Is there a reason you want an ON/OFF on the thermostat as opposed to turning off the breaker?

Comment: @AlaskaMan: Sorry for l-o-o-o-ng delay in replying. Didn't see the notification.  I want the baseboard to stop drawing electricity. Even at the lowest level it was staying a little warm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just about the only way this could happen is that the switch part of the thermostat has jammed or welded itself in the ON position.  The double-pole breaker controls 240V, switching both black (hot) wires.  The thermostat is also double-pole i.e. it switches both black wires.  Tandem is a different thing.  You can replace this thermostat with virtually any double-pole mechanical line-voltage thermostat, most are rated to handle up to 22A of load on a 240V circuit which means they can handle your heater which is 18A or less.